# Como eu faço somátorio na linguagem R?

Tags: r, matemática, soma

[Preciso calcular esse somátorio em R, sei que tem a função sum(), mas nao sei como usar nesse caso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7qrQ.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com os limites de cada somatório crie um vetor `i` e aplique cada fómula.

```r
# a)
i <- 10:100
sum(i^3 + 4*i^2)
#> [1] 26852735

# b)
i <- 10:25
sum(2^i/i + 3^i/i^2)
#> [1] 2129169868
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Sem criar os vetores `i` o código não é muito menos legível.

```r
# a)
sum((10:100)^3 + 4*(10:100)^2)
#> [1] 26852735

# b)
sum(2^(10:25)/(10:25) + 3^(10:25)/(10:25)^2)
#> [1] 2129169868
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>